# Preview with fineuploader not working when using manual trigger

Tags: fine-uploader

I can't get the preview working with the fineuploader when using the manual triggering , I have put the drawthumbnail into the submit and submitted event but nothing works. I am using one of the stackoverflow examples as a base. I am sure that the event is triggered as the log fires:

```
[FineUploader 4.1.0] Attempting to update thumbnail based on server response.
[FineUploader 4.1.0] Rendering template in DOM.
[FineUploader 4.1.0] Template rendering complete
[FineUploader 4.1.0] Received 1 files or inputs.
On submit
Calling draw thumbnail on id: 0 with filename: 2013-01-06 17.14.37.jpg
On submitted
Calling draw thumbnail on id: 0 with filename: 2013-01-06 17.14.37.jpg


$('#myFineUploaderContainer').fineUploader({
   debug: true,
   template: "qq-simple-thumbnails-template",
   thumbnails: {
          placeholders: {
            waitingPath: "/static//img/loading.gif",
            notAvailablePath: "/static//img/loading.gif"
          }},
   request: {
      endpoint: '/ajaxuploadmms',
   params: {
    'csrf_token': 'XXXXX',
    'csrf_name': 'csrfmiddlewaretoken',
    'csrf_xname': 'X-CSRFToken',
    },
   customHeaders: {
    'X-CSRFToken': 'XXXXX',
    'test': 'test',}},
   autoUpload: false,
   validation: {
                allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
            },
   showMessage: function(message) {
        // Using Bootstrap's classes
        $('#myFineUploaderContainer').append('<div class="alert alert-error">' + message + '</div>');
      }

}).on('upload', function(event, id, name) {
        var enteredMessage = $('#message').val();
    var group = $('.dropdown-menu li a').val();
    $(this).fineUploader('setParams', {'group': window.group,'message': enteredMessage, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': 'XXXXX'}, id);
}).on('submit', function (event, id, filename) {
    console.log('On submit');
    console.log('Calling draw thumbnail on id: ' +id+ ' with filename: ' +filename );
    $(this).fineUploader("drawThumbnail", id, document.getElementById('picture'), 200, false);
}).on('submitted', function (event, id, filename) {
    console.log('On submitted');
        console.log('Calling draw thumbnail on id: ' +id+ ' with filename: ' +filename );
        $(this).fineUploader('drawThumbnail', id, document.getElementById('picture'), 200, false);

}).on('complete', function (event, id, name, response) {
        console.log('Complete callback called on id: '+id+'. Response was: '+JSON.stringify(response));
        //remove active class from progress bar. remove cancel button from filename
        $fileItem = $(this).fineUploader("getItemByFileId", id);
        $fileName = $(this).fineUploader("getName", id);
        if (response.success) {
            $fileItem.find(".progress").removeClass("active").removeClass("progress-info").removeClass("progress-striped").addClass("progress-success");
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-cancel").remove();
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-status-text").addClass("green-text");
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-status-text").html("- Completed");
        }

        if (response.error) {
            $fileItem.find(".progress").removeClass("active").removeClass("progress-info").removeClass("progress-striped").addClass("progress-danger");
            $fileItem.find(".bar").removeClass("bar-success").addClass("bar-danger");
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-cancel").remove();
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-status-text").addClass("red-text");
            $fileItem.find(".qq-upload-status-text").html("- Upload failed!");
            $("#fineUploader").prepend('<div id="flashMessage" class="alert alert-error"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><p>Upload failed on <b>'+$fileName+'</b>! Please try uploading it again.</p></div>');
        }

        //check to see if there are any uploads happening still. if not, reload the page use getInProgress() API call
        $uploadingFiles = $(this).fineUploader("getInProgress");

        //close the modal if no uploads are in progress. refresh media index. pop up success banner.
        if ($uploadingFiles < 1) {
            //uploads_done();
        }

    });


$('#uploadSelectedFiles').click(function() {
   $('#myFineUploaderContainer').fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
});
});
  </script>

    <script type="text/template" id="qq-simple-thumbnails-template">
        <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader">
            <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
                <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
            </div>
            <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
                <div>Upload a file</div>
            </div>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
                <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
                <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
            </span>
            <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list">
                <li>
                    <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector progress">
                        <div class="qq-progress-bar-selector progress-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                    <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                    <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="100" qq-server-scale>
                    <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon"></span>
                    <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                    <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                    <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                    <a class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel" href="#">Cancel</a>
                    <a class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry" href="#">Retry</a>
                    <a class="qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete" href="#">Delete</a>
                    <span class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </script>

</div>
```

EDITED:
I have chrome and this is the supported features

```
qq.supportedFeatures
Object {uploading: true, ajaxUploading: false, fileDrop: false, folderDrop: false, chunking: false…}
ajaxUploading: false
canDetermineSize: false
chunking: false
deleteFileCors: false
deleteFileCorsXdr: false
deleteFileCorsXhr: false
fileDrop: false
folderDrop: false
folderSelection: true
imagePreviews: false
imageValidation: false
itemSizeValidation: false
pause: false
progressBar: false
resume: false
uploadCors: true
uploadCustomHeaders: false
uploadNonMultipart: false
uploadViaPaste: false
uploading: true
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: I have not included the whole HTML but there is img with the requested id.

Comment: <img id="picture" src="/static//img/not_available-generic.png" class="qq-thumbnail-selector">

Comment: Include all of the relevant code in your question if you'd like assistance.  Leaving out bits and pieces of code that are directly related to your question, or posting a question with invalid markup is going to make it much more difficult to help.

Comment: If you have time the form is accessible on this url http://gruppu.com/uploadform2

Comment: I don't want to post the whole HTML markup here as it's too big and some users were complaining when I did that before.

Comment: I took a look at your live code, and confirmed that the element you are attempting to render the preview to does not exist.  Setting a breakpoint on the line that attempts to draw the thumbnail confirms that there is no element with an id of "picture2".

Comment: That was copy past error when copying the original HTML. Even when I put the correct HTML id , it doesn't work:

        $(this).fineUploader("drawThumbnail", id, document.getElementById('picture'), 200, false);

<img id="picture" src="/static//img/not_available-generic.png" class="qq-thumbnail-selector">

Comment: You'll need to upgrade to version 4.2 or greater.  Previous to 4.2, the file was not added to the internal upload handler when autoUpload was set to false until `uploadStoredFiles` was called, and the underlying file was not available to API calls until files were added to this handler.  This internal logic changed in 4.3 as part of feature #784.  https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/784

Comment: Tried with 4.3.1 and still doesn't work , not sure where the issue is ...

Comment: The example url has the updated fineuploader

Comment: I have chrome browser and it seems that the preview is not supported:

 // If client-side preview generation is possible
                // and we are not specifically looking for the image URl returned by the server...
                if (!fromServer && qq.supportedFeatures.imagePreviews) {
                    fileOrUrl = this.getFile(fileId);
                }

I don't pass the above check

Comment: If Chrome is reporting that image previews are not possible, then there is some serious issues with the version of Chrome you have installed.  Perhaps an extension or some other library is causing problems.

Comment: I just took a look at your app.  Some other library has indeed hijacked `window.XMLHttpRequest`.  It looks like the offending library is dajaxice.core.js.  After taking a quick peek at the code, it looks like this library replaces `window.XMLHttpRequest` with a wrapper.  Fine Uploader is choking because this wrapper has hidden some important properties of XHR.  I'd remove dajaxice ASAP.  `window` objects should never be modified in this manner.

Comment: You are right , i then found a couple of same issues on stack overflow with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no element in your markup with an ID of "picture", though you are asking Fine Uploader to render the thumbnail to this element.  Also, the markup in your question is invalid.  You have a closing div without an opening div.

Comment: The code in your question is attempting to draw a preview on an element with an ID of "picture", without a corresponding element in your question's markup.  Your live code is attempting to draw a preview on an element with an id of "picture2", which does not exist in the DOM.